# Determining the number of buckets in Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a question regarding the number of buckets to be used. I understand the uses of bucketing and how it positively impacts SMB joins and sampling. But what if the data volume spikes exponentially?

Let's say looking at the initial data volume, I decide to use 4 buckets and partitioned by day. When I insert into this table it would take 4 reducers at some point (Last job in the insertion query). This is fine. But lets say the data volume suddenly spikes a whole lot for some partitions. It would still take 4 reducers which is not optimal and it is also possible it could fail with OOM.

I could decide on using more buckets initially but that would start creating too many small files until I reach the high volume, as each bucket goes into a file.

Is it possible to have more than one file for a bucket value?

Your inputs are appreciated.

K

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on 'your data volume suddenly spikes a whole lot for some partitions', you could consider using [list bucketing](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ListBucketing#ListBucketing-SkewedTablevs.ListBucketingTable), which allows you to put bucketed column values with low volume into one directory.